# RHEL 7 GUI access

Tags: linux, rhel, xdmcp

I need a replacement browser. Currently we use Exceed to access our RHEL 6.4 box. Works pretty well.

Now, on our replacement RHEL 7.2 box, XDMCP with GDM does not work. Why is not important, but it seems to lead back to an install from the OEM. Vendors, vendors, and more vendors are working the issue. They all are telling us that XDMCP is no longer recommended.

Since I cannot arrange access for our users via our current Exceed browser, what is a good replacement for remote host access? Does anyone know what is recommended?

Requirements: Runs on Windows, GUI, Nautilus, desktop access, new terminals and GUI open quickly within the app.

Comment: You need something like `RDP` access to your Red Hat machine?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: I achieve something like that with `Tiger VNC` on Red Hat and `Real VNC` on my windows machine...you can follow this guide and if you get stuck I could help: http://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-vnc-server-centos-7-rhel-7/

Comment: Redhat recommends the same.

Comment: And it works now.